# Convert the nested json into a dictionary format with no nested objects

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have the input data in below format:

```
data = [[u'Richard', u'48', [u'Josh', u'Beth'], {u'city': u'Seattle', u'Disability': u'no', u'enterprenuer': u'yes'}], [u'Bryan', u'32',[], {u'city': u'NY', u'enterprenuer': u'no', u'wfh': u'yes', u'disability': u'no', u'Visa': u'no'}]]
```

Which later on doing `json.dumps` becomes:

```
[["Richard", "48", ["Josh", "Beth"], {"city": "Seattle", "enterprenuer": "yes", "Disability": "no"}], ["Bryan", "32", [], {"Visa": "no", "city": "NY", "wfh": "yes", "enterprenuer": "no", "disability": "no"}]]
```

Also, I have another list which holds the keys for the dict:

```
key_list = ["Name", "Age", "Children", "details"]
```

I tried the below code:

```
list_of_dicts = []
for d in data:
    dict = {}
    for i in range(0, len(key_list)-1):
        dict[key_list[i]] = d[i]
    list_of_dicts.append(dict)
```

With this I was able to get `new_dict`:

```
[{'Age': u'48', 'Name': u'Richard', 'Children': [u'Josh', u'Beth']}, {'Age': u'32', 'Name': u'Bryan', 'Children': []}]
```

But I am not able to get the nested dict from `data` into the `new_dict` without the need to run code on it again. I don't want to run operation multiple times.
Also, I was thinking if there's any better way to remove the nested list as well but after multiple hit and trial I got side tracked and messed up my code.

This is the expected output:

```
[{"Name":"Richard","Age":"48","Children":"Josh,Beth","city":"Seattle","enterprenuer":"yes","Disability":"no"},{"Name":"Bryan","Age":"32","Children":"","Visa":"no","city":"NY","wfh":"yes","enterprenuer":"no","disability":"no"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

1) in python3:

```
from pprint import pprint

data = [["Richard", "48", ["Josh", "Beth"], {"city": "Seattle", "enterprenuer": "yes", "Disability": "no"}], ["Bryan", "32", [], {"Visa": "no", "city": "NY", "wfh": "yes", "enterprenuer": "no", "disability": "no"}]]
key_list = ["Name", "Age", "Children", "details"]

pprint([dict(zip(key_list[:2], e[:2]), **{key_list[2]: ','.join(e[2])}, **e[3]) for e in data])
```

output:

```
[{'Name': 'Richard',
  'Age': '48',
  'Children': 'Josh,Beth',
  'city': 'Seattle',
  'Disability': 'no',
  'enterprenuer': 'yes'},
 {'Name': 'Bryan',
  'Age': '32',
  'Children': '',
  'city': 'NY',
  'enterprenuer': 'no',
  'wfh': 'yes',
  'disability': 'no',
  'Visa': 'no'}]
```

2) in python2:

```
pprint([dict(zip(key_list[:2], e[:2]), **dict([(key_list[2], ','.join(e[2]))], **e[3])) for e in data])
```

output:

```
[{'Age': '48',
  'Children': 'Josh,Beth',
  'Disability': 'no',
  'Name': 'Richard',
  'city': 'Seattle',
  'enterprenuer': 'yes'},
 {'Age': '32',
  'Children': '',
  'Name': 'Bryan',
  'Visa': 'no',
  'city': 'NY',
  'disability': 'no',
  'enterprenuer': 'no',
  'wfh': 'yes'}]
```

Comment: Thanks @rusu_ro1 for checking on the problem. I tried running this but it seems to give out a Syntax error for me. Can you please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.

```
>>> pprint([dict(zip(key_list[:2], e[:2]), **{key_list[2]: ','.join(e[2])}, **e[3]) for e in data])                                                File "<stdin>", line 1
    pprint([dict(zip(key_list[:2], e[:2]), **{key_list[2]: ','.join(e[2])}, **e[3]) for e in data])
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [["Richard", "48", ["Josh", "Beth"], {"city": "Seattle", "enterprenuer": "yes", "Disability": "no"}], ["Bryan", "32", [], {"Visa": "no", "city": "NY", "wfh": "yes", "enterprenuer": "no", "disability": "no"}]]
key_list = ["Name", "Age", "Children", "details"]

out = []
for item in data:
    d = {}
    out.append(d)
    for value, keyname in zip(item, key_list):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            d.update(**value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            d[keyname] = ','.join(value)
        else:
            d[keyname] = value

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'Age': '48',
  'Children': 'Josh,Beth',
  'Disability': 'no',
  'Name': 'Richard',
  'city': 'Seattle',
  'enterprenuer': 'yes'},
 {'Age': '32',
  'Children': '',
  'Name': 'Bryan',
  'Visa': 'no',
  'city': 'NY',
  'disability': 'no',
  'enterprenuer': 'no',
  'wfh': 'yes'}]
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, this worked, just a edit though
```
        if isinstance(value, type(dict)):
            d.update(**value)
        elif isinstance(value, type(key_list)):
```

Also, I am getting few empty lists in the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple unpacking:

```
data = [[u'Richard', u'48', [u'Josh', u'Beth'], {u'city': u'Seattle', u'Disability': u'no', u'enterprenuer': u'yes'}], [u'Bryan', u'32',[], {u'city': u'NY', u'enterprenuer': u'no', u'wfh': u'yes', u'disability': u'no', u'Visa': u'no'}]]
key_list = ["Name", "Age", "Children", "details"]
r = [{**dict(zip(key_list[:-1], a[:-1]+[','.join(a[-1])])), **b} for *a, b in data]
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'Richard', 'Age': '48', 'Children': 'Josh,Beth', 'city': 'Seattle', 'Disability': 'no', 'enterprenuer': 'yes'}, {'Name': 'Bryan', 'Age': '32', 'Children': '', 'city': 'NY', 'enterprenuer': 'no', 'wfh': 'yes', 'disability': 'no', 'Visa': 'no'}]
```

Edit: Python2.7 solution:

```
data = [[u'Richard', u'48', [u'Josh', u'Beth'], {u'city': u'Seattle', u'Disability': u'no', u'enterprenuer': u'yes'}], [u'Bryan', u'32',[], {u'city': u'NY', u'enterprenuer': u'no', u'wfh': u'yes', u'disability': u'no', u'Visa': u'no'}]]
key_list = ["Name", "Age", "Children", "details"] 
r = [dict(zip(key_list[:-1], i[:2]+[','.join(i[2])])+i[-1].items()) for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[{u'city': u'Seattle', 'Name': u'Richard', 'Age': u'48', u'enterprenuer': u'yes', u'Disability': u'no', 'Children': u'Josh,Beth'}, {u'city': u'NY', u'wfh': u'yes', 'Name': u'Bryan', 'Age': u'32', u'enterprenuer': u'no', u'disability': u'no', u'Visa': u'no', 'Children': ''}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajax1234, Can you help with this in python2.7