# Convert nested structures into string

Tags: python, json, string, python-2.7, list

My data consists of multiple nested dict and lists, I am trying to convert the list to a dictionary where within one element of the dictionary there is no nested structures.

```
data = [
    [
        u'abc', u'1.2.3.4', 52, 
        [u'prod', u'linux'], 
        u'jack',
        [u'2019-08-15', u'2019-06-10'],  
        {u'dc': u'NA', u'network': u'public'}
    ], 
    [
        u'xyz', u'127.0.0.1', 126, 
        [u'prod', u'linux', u'backup'], 
        u'rich', 
        [u'2019-03-21', u'2019-05-01'], 
        {u'network': u'public', u'owner': u'security team'}
    ],
    [
        u'pqr', u'5.6.7.8', 125,  
        [u'stage', u'ubuntu'],
         u'kevin', 
         [], 
        {u'newtwork': u'private', u'type': u'sql', u'owner': u'security team'}
    ]
]
```

```
key_list = ['hostname', 'ip_address', 'num_process', 'usage', 'user', 'restarts', 'tags']
```

I tried using `zip()` but I was able to get close to what I wanted to achieve as the last element from key_list `tags` kept bothering me there.
I came across this page 
[Convert the nested json into a dictionary format with no nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57584924/convert-the-nested-json-into-a-dictionary-format-with-no-nested-objects/57594531?noredirect=1#comment101646878_57594531)

This gave me hope but later I found in this solution the data had only one nested list so the approach is good for that but my data has multiple nested lists and in future that will also increase.

How can I perfect the code such that if in future as well new lists are coming in the data the solution is not affected.

```
[
    {
        "hostname":"abc",
        "ip_address":"1.2.3.4",
        "num_process":"52",
        "usage":"prod, linux",
        "owner":"jack",
        "restarts":"2019-08-15, 2019-06-10",
        "dc":"NA",
        "network":"public"
    },
    {
    "hostname":"xyz",
    "ip_address":"127.0.0.1",
    "num_process":"126",
    "usage":"prod, linux,backup",
    "user":"rich",
    "restarts":"2019-03-21, 2019-05-01",
    "owner":"security team",
    "network":"public"
    },
    {
        "hostname":"pqr",
        "ip_address":"5.6.7.8",
        "num_process":"125",
        "usage":"stage, ubuntu",
        "owner":"kevin",
        "restarts":"",
        "user":"security team",
        "newtwork":"private",
        "type":"sql"
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It will show what you try even if it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get_mapping(data, keys):
    for entry in data:
        result = dict(zip(key_list, (value for value in entry if not isinstance(value, dict))))
        for value in entry:
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                result.update(value)
        yield result

list(get_mapping(data, key_list))
```

Output:

```
[{'hostname': 'abc',
  'ip_address': '1.2.3.4',
  'num_process': 52,
  'usage': ['prod', 'linux'],
  'user': 'jack',
  'restarts': ['2019-08-15', '2019-06-10'],
  'dc': 'NA',
  'network': 'public'},
 {'hostname': 'xyz',
  'ip_address': '127.0.0.1',
  'num_process': 126,
  'usage': ['prod', 'linux', 'backup'],
  'user': 'rich',
  'restarts': ['2019-03-21', '2019-05-01'],
  'network': 'public',
  'owner': 'security team'},
 {'hostname': 'pqr',
  'ip_address': '5.6.7.8',
  'num_process': 125,
  'usage': ['stage', 'ubuntu'],
  'user': 'kevin',
  'restarts': [],
  'newtwork': 'private',
  'type': 'sql',
  'owner': 'security team'}]
```